# pandas grouped plot chart groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, data-visualization, exploratory-data-analysis, grouped-bar-chart

Tried to create grouped bar chart in pandas. Data looks like this

| month | companyname | profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dec | a | 20 |
| jan | a | 30 |
| feb | a | 50 |
| dec | c | 80 |
| jan | c | 20 |
| feb | c | 34 |
| dec | b | 20 |
| jan | b | 30 |
| feb | b | 50 |
| dec | a | 20 |
| jan | a | 30 |
| feb | a | 50 |

- x axis: company name
- y axis: profit
- hue: month.

Desired Output:

[image: bargraph]

Comment: Try `df.pivot_table('profit', 'companyname', 'month').plot.bar()` or to sum values `df.pivot_table('profit', 'companyname', 'month', aggfunc='sum').plot.bar()`

Comment: Thank you so much..but the month order is not correct.How can i fix that?

Comment: see solution below, we can fix with using months to reorder dataframe columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.barplot(data=df, x='companyname', y='profit', hue='month')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thankyou verymuch. There is a line on each plot. how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import calendar

month_order = map(str.lower, calendar.month_abbr[1:]) 
df.pivot_table('profit', 'companyname', 'month')\
  .reindex(month_order, axis=1)\
  .dropna(how='all', axis=1)\
  .plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Note: Here I `import calendar` to get the month abbreviation order and use `map` to `lower`case the string to match your data, then use `pd.DataFrame.reindex` to reorder the columns and plotted.